# Dilution problem

Tags: ratio, dimensional-analysis

I was attempting to solve a dilution problem by use of dimensional analysis but I am not sure if there was a better method or formula

The problem:

A solution uses 40 ounces of water for every 8 ounces of solute. How much solute is needed to fill a 24 ounce container?

---

$\dfrac{8 oz solute}{1}$ * $\dfrac{1}{40 oz water}$ * $\dfrac{24 oz container}{1}$ = $\dfrac{4.8 oz solute}{1 oz water}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimensional analysis is not the answer. 8 oz solute yields (40+8) oz = 48 oz solution. If your solution has a volume of 24 ounces, you need to multiply each quantity by 24/48=1/2, so you need 40/2=20 oz water and 8/2=4 oz solute